# Target Config to expose a LWC in both Desktop & Mobile

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-apps, lightning-record-page

I have created a Lightning Component & i want to expose the same in both Desktop & mobile. I used the following in the meta.xml file,the component is either visible in desktop or mobile.. but i need to achieve both - any help regarding this is much appreciated.

```
  <targets>
    <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
</targets>
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
        <supportedFormFactors>
            <supportedFormFactor type="small" />
        </supportedFormFactors>
    </targetConfig>

</targetConfigs>
```

The problem i'm facing is i'm not able to add another targetConfig for "lightning__RecordPage" nor am i able to add supportedFormFactor type="Large" in the existing targetConfig for "lightning__RecordPage".

TIA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by adding another `<supportedFormFactor type="Small" />` in `<supportedFormFactors>`:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>42.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Best Component Ever</masterLabel>
    <description>This is a demo component.</description>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="prop1" type="String" />
            <supportedFormFactors>
                <supportedFormFactor type="Large" />
                <supportedFormFactor type="Small" />
            </supportedFormFactors>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

> Also, If you don’t define , the component
>   supports the form factors that the page type supports. If your
>   lightning page supports both mobile and desktop form factor, It will
>   apply for the component exist on the page.

App and record pages support the Large and Small form factors. Home pages support only the Large form factor.

[image]

Comment: This worked. Initially i had set the form factor to both phone & mobile - so i dint get "Add Another Form Factor". I set to phone & then i was able to get "Add Another Form Factor" button, after which i chose Desktop.

Comment: what is property name for under the target config?